# set an id on jQuery datatables to be used by TableDnD plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table which I am loading data into from a server side PHP script which returns the table as JSON for jQuery dataTables to render.  I am then using the jQuery tableDnD plugin to allow drag and drop re-ordering of tables, this requires that the rows of the table contain the id matching the table row in the database ie `<tr id="1">`

I am wondering how I can achieve this using dataTables as it doesn't allow me to specify this.

My current thinking is to use a callback on the data maybe, that or rewrite tableDnD to read the id value from an index column, does anyone have any ideas regarding this?

Answer (score 4):

The call back proved to be the answer,

```
    $('#dataTable').dataTable( {
    ...
        "aoColumns" : [
            { sWidth:'40px' },
            { sWidth:'40px',sClass:'position' },
            ...
            { sWidth:'3px',sClass:'handle' }
        ],
            ...
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
            $(nRow).attr("id",aData[0]);
            return nRow;
        },
```

using the `fnRowCallback` I was able to add the attribute id to the table row and then load it with the id which was the first element of data returned `aData[0]`

I found I can use the `"aoColumns"` to load both width and the classes 'position', and 'handle' needed for my jQuery tableDnD.

I guess I should read the manual a bit more next time!

Comment: You should accept your own answer, perhaps it will help other people in the future.